# Why does my function run twice in every step of a ForEach loop?

Tags: swiftui

I have the following code:

```
func hasAppointment1(_ iAppointment: Int) -> Bool {
    print("iAppointment: \(iAppointment)")
   return true
 }


  var body: some View {

    List {
      ForEach(1..<4) { iAppointment in
        if hasAppointment1(iAppointment) {
                Text("\(iAppointment)")
        }
      }
    }
```

In the Simulator I get a list of three items: "1","2" and "3", perfectly what I want.
In the console however I get:
iAppointment: 1
iAppointment: 1
iAppointment: 2
iAppointment: 2
iAppointment: 3
iAppointment: 3

So hasAppointment1 is executed twice for each step in the ForEach loop.

I would however expect the function "hasAppointment1" to run only once per ForEach step.
I tried with "ForEach(1..<4, id: \self)" but same behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ForEach` is not a loop, it's a `View` data struct and its closure can be called many times.

Also, the `if` inside ForEach's closure is a bad idea, better to just not include that item in the data supplied to `ForEach`.

You can learn how to prepare and pass your data into the `ForEach` data struct in the docs:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/foreach